# Error al mostrar imagen almacenada en Storage

Tags: laravel

estoy trabajando en ambiente local (con xampp) almacenando imagenes en un carpeta dentro del directorio Storage (hice el enlace simbolico), estoy trabajando con una relacion polimorfica para el tema de las imagenes (es decir, guardo el modelo al que corresponde la imagen, la ruta y despues lo recupero desde mi vista) pero me doy cuenta que al recuperar la imagen, me arroja la url de la imagen como un dominio local (http://digitalbits.test/storage/posts/v0szXngLlmq0QZ6yBPGnGYnjp8PRANidrOdHsvfQ.jpg) y obviamente no carga la imagen... tengo en mi controlador en el metodo store asi:

```
$post = new Post();
        //$post->fecha_publicacion = $request->fecha_publicacion;
        $post->titulo = $request->titulo;
        $post->slug = $request->slug;
        $post->extracto = $request->extracto;
        $post->cuerpo = $request->cuerpo;
        $post->status = $request->status;
        $post->user_id = $request->user_id;
        $post->categoria_id = $request->categoria_id;
        $post->save();


        //post = Post::create($request->all());

       if($request->hasFile('file')){
            $url = Storage::put('posts', $request->file('file'));

            $image = new ImgPost(['url_imagen' => $url]);
            // insertas la Image directamente desde el método de save() de la relación
            $post->image()->save($image);


        }

        $tag_id = $request->get('tags');
        $cont = 0;
        while($cont < count ($tag_id)){
           $tag = new PostTag();
           $tag->post_id = $post->id;
           $tag->tag_id = $input['tags'] = $request->input('tags')[$cont];
            //$detalleIngreso->servicio_id = $servicio_id[$cont];
           $tag->save();
           $cont=$cont+1;
        }

        return redirect()->route('admin.blog.index');
```

Y en la vista lo recupero de esta manera:

```
 @if ($post->image)
                            <img src="{{ Storage::url($post->image->url_imagen)}}" class="img-fluid" alt="">

                                <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                            @else
                            <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/images/48.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                            <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>

                            @endif
```

En la Tabla de la BD, la ruta me la guardo correctamente: **posts/v0szXngLlmq0QZ6yBPGnGYnjp8PRANidrOdHsvfQ.jpg**

Saludos a todos

Comment: Qué valor tiene APP_URL en el archivo .env?